# .dem conversion error

Tags: qgis, convert, sketchup

When trying to convert a .tif file into a .dem file (for import into sketchup 2017) using QGIS Raster > Conversion > Translate, I get the following error messages with multiple instances of the first line (presumably 529 instances);

---

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: tmerc: Invalid latitude

ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.

Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,142,190, skipping.
```

Input file size is 142, 190

---

A layer is created and a .dem file saved but there is nothing visible in the QGIS layer and sketchup won't import the .dem file.
Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried reproject, then convert

Comment: I have ensured the dem CRS is the same as the source tif. Is that what reproject would be trying to achieve?